# Can´t connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

Tags: mysql

Im trying to connet to 127.0.0.1 using Sequel Pro:

```
Name: test

Host: 127.0.0.1

user: root
```

But it appears an error:

```
Connection failed, Can´t connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

If I execute the command:

```
 mysql.server start
```

It appears the error:

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/John.local.pid).
```

Do you know how to fix?

Full error:

```
my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
Starting MySQL
.my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/John.local.pid).
```

Comment: Check the MySQL error log and post the error you're seeing when you try to start MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, I update the question with that.

Comment: try `sudo mysql.server start`

Comment: Thanks, but also dont works!

Comment: Does this file exist? '/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d'
Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: Just the /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/31760

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql`, maybe it is only

Answer (score 0):

Install homebrew, https://brew.sh/ or write following command

- $ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

To make or change directory please run following command

- mkdir /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d

Link mysql

- `brew link mysql`

Restart MySQL

- `brew services restart mysql`

If that process not work, please backup your database and reinstall MySQL